# Trigonometical sum from Fourier analysis

Tags: trigonometric-series, exponential-sum

(**Edit**) Note: $a\in \mathbb{R},0<a\leq\pi$. Also, the sum skips $n=0$ (that's where the other term comes from).

Working through a Fourier analysis exercise I've got stuck in a clearly trigonometical step. I've arrived at:

$$1=\frac{1}{2\pi}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\frac{na}{2}}{\pi ne^{ina/2}}$$

And I need to reduce the infinite sum to one of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(na)}{\pi n}$.

Euler's formula and half-angle formulae doesn't seem to help. Any idea?

Comment: Is $a$ an integer?

Comment: You sum contains a zero division for n=0. Also, does sen mean sin?

Comment: I think this question is lacking some details/data.

Comment: "sen" is Spanish or Italian for "sin".

Comment: most audience here is not spanish

Comment: It never matters the language: it's been said many times in the past that askers can post in whatever language they want, andthen hope that fortunately enough someone can understand them and answer them. It is isn't forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{na}{2})}{\pi ne^{ina/2}}
\\=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(na/2)e^{-ina/2}}{\pi n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(na/2)[\cos(na/2)-i\sin(na/2)]}{\pi n}
\\=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac12\sin(na)}{\pi n}-i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac12[1-\cos(na)]}{n\pi}
\\=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac12\sin(na)}{\pi n}+i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac12\cos(na)}{n\pi}-\underbrace{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2n\pi}}_{x+(-x)=0}
\\=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ina}}{2\pi n}=S_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ian}+e^{-ian}}{2}.\frac{1}{n\pi}=S_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(na)}{n\pi}$$
I don't know what to do about $S_0$(i.e., when $n=0$).

Hope rest is clear and it helped you.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. I took the $S_0$ out of the sum and forgot to mention it.